# MVC - Criar uma model tipada sendo uma lista genérica

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Gostaria de criar uma Model tipada sendo ela uma lista do tipo `T`.

Utilizando: Razor do ASP.NET MVC 5
Por exemplo:
Meu model no `cshtml` ficará assim:

```
@model List<T>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h1>@item.name</h2>
}
```

É possível?

Comment: Do jeito que você fez não... Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: Mas teria algum jeito de conseguir este resultado? Provável que não né?

Comment: Objetivo é de usar ela como partial view... que irá listar o objeto da lista. (Independente do tipo da lista)

Comment: Bruno a `View` precisa conhecer o tipo que você está enviando, dessa forma uma `View` com o tipo Genérico não daria... só se fosse um `View` com os mesmos campos

Comment: @BrunoHeringer você quer criar uma view parcial pra economizar 5 linhas de código??

Comment: @LINQ acho que ele quer economizar em arquivos `cshtml`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use Interfaces**

Veja só, sua View espera receber uma lista de objetos ondem eles necessariamente tenha a propriedade `Name`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h1>@item.name</h2>
}
```

Então, criamos um contrato para deixarmos claro para esses objetos que eles são obrigados a implementar essa propriedade, que também a `View` que qualquer objeto dessa lista terá sim uma propriedade `Name`.

```
public interface ITemQueTerPropName
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Agora avisa isso para sua View, assim ela irá se comportar como esperado:

```
@model List<ITemQueTerPropName>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h1>@item.Name</h2>
}
```

E não esquece de implementar a interface nos objetos pertinentes:

```
public class UmObjetoQueIraAparecerNaView : ITemQueTerPropName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Assim sua `View` vai se comportar como esperado, e também irá garantir que sua view só irá renderizar objetos que possuam a propriedade `Name`.

Comment: Apenas para informar que no terceiro bloco de código, você abriu uma tag <h1> e fechou com </h2>